# When is stateless bean instantiated?

Tags: java, javabeans, java-ee-7

I'm writing JavaEE-based application and I'm not entirely sure when an how dependency inject happens. Lets say I have Two classes:

```
@Stateless
class RepoBean {
@Resource
private SomeResource someResource;

public List<SomeObject> search(String someQuery) {// implementation}
}
```

and

```
@Stateless 
class ServiceBean {
@EJB
private RepoBean repoBean;

public void search(List<String> someQueries {
    for (String someQuery : someQueries) {
        List<SomeObject> someObjects = this.repoBean.search(someQuery)
        for (SomeObject someObject : someObjects) {
            // handle someObject)
        }
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. When is the repo bean instantiated? On Service instantiation or on use?
2. If this loop is N objects "long" will there be only one repoBean instance used in iteration or each time the pool will be asked for RepoBean instance and I have no guarantee that the repo will be the same?
3. Is there any way to make sure that all of the queries are run on the same instance of RepoBean other than modifying repo's search method to `Map<String, List<SomeObject>> search(List<String> searchQueries)`

Answer (score 1):

Stateless bean instantiation is lazy. If application starts an empty Stateless-EJB pool also called *free pool* will be created. On first client request a concrete *RepoBean* instance will be created, used and put then into the free pool. The size of the pool is configurable. After some inactivity time the instances will be destroyed and removed from the pool.

`this.repoBean` will be always the same inside of `ServiceBean#search` method and so long as a parent `ServiceBean` instance is alive.